# How to pass a specific value with onItemClick to new activity

Tags: android, json, listview

I have tried various different methods using myIntent.putExtra("name", ); Nothing works to retrieve the "TAG_NAME" of the item i click in list view. It opens the new activity without an issue, but the value passed is null. The second activity is almost identical to this one, so i will not place it as well. Only difference is how many json nodes i have declared and the fact that I want to use a switch based on the category name that i take from the main activity. Thus, depending on what was clicked, the json will use a different URL for the data.

I need help figuring how i can pass the category name (TAG_NAME) that was pressed.

EDIT: Quick note - the code below works perfectly to display the list view with the data provided in the url. Also, when clicking and not using the data which is passed (and is always null), but a static url, the second activity's code works like a charm as well. My only issue is the passed variable.

```
 public class Main_activity extends ListActivity {


  //URL to get JSON Array
  private static String url = "http://localhost/category";
  //JSON Node Names
  private static final String CAT ="categories";
  private static final String TAG_NAME = "name"; //copy-paste to other same static string variables
  JSONArray categories  = null;
  private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new JSONParse().execute();


    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), happy_products.class); 
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
            // display happy_products.class     
        }
       });
     }


    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
       private ProgressDialog pDialog;
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          // Showing progress dialog
          pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main_happy.this);
          pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
          pDialog.setCancelable(false);
          pDialog.show();
      }
      @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
          ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

          // Making a request to url and getting response
          String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

          Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

          if (jsonStr != null) {
              try {
        // Getting JSON from URL
             JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
              categories = jsonObj.getJSONArray(CAT);
            for(int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            // Adding value HashMap key => value
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            oslist.add(map);
              }
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
     }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void r) {
          super.onPostExecute(r);
          // Dismiss the progress dialog
          if (pDialog.isShowing())
              pDialog.dismiss();
          /**
           * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
           * */
          ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main_happy.this, oslist,
                  R.layout.category_list,
                  new String[] {TAG_ID, TAG_NAME,TAG_UPDATE}, new int[] {R.id.id,R.id.name, R.id.lastUpdated});
          setListAdapter(adapter);
      }

    }
}
```

EDIT in response to first comment:

Might be I am not using the right key. The error is related to the null value returned, thus the  doInBackground is unable to get the data as the url is null. 
'

```
HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap<String,String>)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String value = map.get(TAG_NAME);
```

'

```
 06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:353)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:725)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at apphap.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:68)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at apphap.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:34)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at apphap._products$JSONParse.doInBackground(_products.java:76)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at apphap._products$JSONParse.doInBackground(_products.java:1)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    06-11 13:10:24.191: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

'

Comment: use `HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap<String,String> ) parent.getItemAtPosition()` Then `String value= map.get("your key")`

Comment: @Raghunandan I tried, but it ended up in an error, one I have seen multiple times when trying various different ways to send the data to the new activity. If the data is null, the DoInBackground is unable to find the url and will fail to retrieve json data as well.
Any ideas? :\

Comment: check your uri. is it right

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, that's not the issue, it works fine

Comment: there is a NPE. Check your response. check the part where you have `HttpGe` <init> in stacktrace says something wrong with initialization and some object is null. Your problem has nothing to with getting the value on list item click

Comment: I tried a different approach in the second activity. 
String name = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
In the switch case that provides the url needed for json, i used the name.length() as my categories have different lengths. However, this time i get the "Unable to start activity Component Info due to the NPE, at the same row as the switch stamenent for name.length(). Doesn't that mean that the value passed from 1st activity is null? :\

Comment: Maybe I am taking the wrong value or need to declare it somehow else. I need that value so i can attach it to another string and form the new URL for the second activity. Is there any way to accomplish that for the above code? The value i need is the ID of the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hashmap was improperly declared (local instead of global) and caused the value passed to be null, thus the errors to appear.

Indeed a rookie mistake, but it's solved now. Just improper declaration on my part. :\

Thanks for the downvotes and well, for the attempt to help me (@Raghunandan).